# Haskell: scan an Array

Tags: haskell

I have an Array of Foos:

```
myArray :: Array Int Foo
```

I would like to "scan" it from left to right using a function similar to:

```
getNextStep :: Bar -> Foo -> Bar
```

I would like to scan myArray to generate an array of Bars:

```
scanl :: (Bar -> Foo -> Bar) -> Bar -> Array Int Foo -> Array Int Bar
```

Yes, this is very similar to prelude's `scanl`. But is there a version for Arrays? Can I build one with e.g. Traversable?
Thanks

Comment: The answer to _"can it be done?"_ questions is almost always _"yes"_ in the programming world, with varying degrees of _"but..."_ Have you made an attempt at this goal?

Comment: It's easy to do by converting from and to lists (toList, fromList). However I was surprised not to find the function `scanl` for Arrays, so I'm wondering if I missed something!

Comment: It might be possible to use `foldr` or `foldl` to produce the behavior of `scanl` here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[mapAccumL](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html#v:mapAccumL) works on any Traversable.  It's a bit more general than a scan but if you use a step function that emits the state value unchanged you more or less get a scan again.

```
> mapAccumL (\s x -> (s + x, s)) 0 [1,2,3,4]
(10,[0,1,3,6])
```

You'd have to add the final element back on to the array if you wanted it to be included like it is with scanl.  Traversables in general don't have a way to add an element, so we can't make that work for any traversable.